# Modifying Xen source code, my own codes don't seems to execute

Tags: python, xen

I am learning Xen, I want to add some my own codes, then make and make install, but when I execute some commands, I can't see any changes. e.g. I add some lines in tools/python/xen/xm/migrate.py

```
def main(argv):
    opts = gopts
    opts.reset()
    args = opts.parse(argv)

    if len(args) != 2:
       raise OptionError('Invalid number of arguments')

    """start of my code"""
    fp = open("/m.log",'w')
    fp.write('start')
    fp.close()
    """end of my code"""
    ....
```

As above, I create a file, and then write something, but after I make && make install, when I execute it, I can't find the file. I logged in root, so I am sure I have approprite priviledge. 
p.s. my Xen version is 4.1.2
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Did everything work before your adjustments because there's a known error with python:    http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Compiling_Xen_From_Source#Python_Prefix_and_Module_Layout  (look in section "Python Prefix and Module Layout", make install PYTHON_PREFIX_ARG= did it for me)